# How often did Carlisle live in Forks?

Tags: twilight

In *Twilight,* Jacob reveals that the Cullens are the same vampires who made a pact with his forebears many decades previously.

Yet the younger Cullens have only been attending school in Forks for a couple years.

Rosalie complains about the idea of having to move “again,” implying they’ve moved often in the past.  The young Cullens have all been through high school many times, in many places.

**How often did Carlisle move out of and back into Forks?  In such a small town how is it he wasn’t remembered from previous stints of living there, even if decades prior?  How could it be that only in La Push is his original visit remembered?**

The expensive house (with metal screens that close over the windows at the push of a button) is the only indication of permanence in the town I recall other than the statement from Jacob.  Everything else seems to fit better if they weren’t there at all, ever, before a few years ago.

Canon answers preferable (books only, not movies), but word of God acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on:

- Jacob's discussion of the cause of werewolves in *New Moon* and *Eclipse* (i.e. the presence or proximity of vampires causes the werewolf "gene" to be activated), and
- the fact that Sam (the first werewolf in this generation) was the first to undergo this transformation since the tribal elders' *grandparents,*

...we can infer that Carlisle and his coven lived in Forks only once before the two years preceding the start of "Twilight."

So the initial time spent living there, and the modern time spent living there, were the only times of residence.

Comment: I would like to clean this up and add quotes from the books, but here is the germ of the answer at least.

Comment: From the information you've supplied here I don't see how you come to the conclusion of "only once before".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot he made the treaty with Ephraim Black, and that’s the last time there was a werewolf pack.  When more vampires show up in Eclipse and Breaking Dawn, it causes an outbreak of more werewolves transforming.  Ergo, had Carlisle come with his coven and lived in Forks at some point in between, there would have been more werewolves—perhaps Billy Black or Harry Clearwater.